# Right Java exception type for calling method before initialization

Tags: java, exception

I have a class that has an explicit initialization method and some other methods that do the actual work:

```
public class Worker {

    public void init(Context context) { /* ... */ };

    public void doWork() { /* ... */ };
}
```

The `Init` method must be called before any actual work is done, which is documented in class and methods description.

I would like to throw an exception from `DoWork` method if initialization wasn't performed before the call. What would be the right exception type for this case? `UnsupportedOperationException`, `IllegalStateException` or something else?

Comment: There's means of an [illegal state](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html).

Comment: @BalusC: yes, thanks, I'm new to Java (hence the newbie question and naming problems). Don't worry, they do in actual code!

Comment: Note that standard Java exceptions usually describe their purpose very well in their javadocs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html). But ideally, try to ensure that the object *always* has a valid state. :-) In this case, by requiring `Context` in the constructor rather than a separate "init" function:

```
public class Worker {

    // Note this is a constructor now, not a method
    public Worker(Context context) {
        /* ... */
    }

    public void doWork() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I do try to ensure that. However, I'm reluctant to put code that performs complex computations or other long-running activities in the constructor, which unfortunally is the case.

Comment: Then don't expose a constructor.  Expose a factory method.

Comment: In which case: have the init function return another object, on which you can call doWork().  This looks suspiciously like the factory pattern :).

Comment: @Dyppl: In general, it's fine to do anything in a constructor that you do in a method. If by "long running" you mean happening on another thread, and so you can have a semi-constructed instance, you can handle that with a factory that accepts a callback (`public static void BuildWorker(Context context, IAcceptWorkers target)`) where `IAcceptWorkers` is an interface with a function you call with the fully-constructed `Worker`. If by long-running you just mean it takes a while, that's fine, still a constructor. Document it, of course. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm not sure I completely agree; at a VM level, sure, but I think there's benefit in separating actually creating the object from the work required to enable me to create the object.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll look into your suggestions

Comment: @AndrewAylett: Yeah, sometimes factory is the way to go even absent the threading thing. Actually, a lot of times, depending on other factors than time. :-)